# Is it possible to hide "Advanced search" option in search view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In Odoo v8. I want to disable it, not single fields inside. That's all.

Comment: add proper description

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please share your efforts in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the css. At end of `\Odoo 8\server\openerp\addons\web\static\src\css\base.css` add:

```
div.oe_searchview_advanced {
  display: none !important;
}
```

May need to restart Odoo.

Comment: Can I assign it to my search view by the "class" attribute? I need to hide it only in some views in my module.

Comment: `body > div.openerp.openerp_webclient_container > table > tbody > tr > td.oe_application > div > div[data-view-type="list"] > div > div > div > div.oe_searchview_drawer_container > div > div.col-md-5 > div.oe_searchview_advanced {display: none !important;}` This will only remove the advanced search for the list view, you can change the data-view-type to apply to others. Not sure if this is what you needed, please add more descriptions. But if you would like to apply this to a specific view in a particular module, not sure if it's possible through CSS.